# "Spread across" vs "Spread through"

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

> The disease spread **through** the region.
>
> The disease spread across the region.

Explain the difference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, there really isn't one. There is possibly some small difference in nuance, but if so it will depend on cultural/dialect-related factors.

However, in almost any other case, ***across*** and ***through*** are not synonyms. Not even in other cases with *spread*, nor other cases of spreading *disease*. They normally have quite different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

> **Spread across**

Is commonly used to **divide** something. for instance:

> We are asking for government funding to preserve a
>   collection that is spread across the country.

On the other hand:

> **Spread through**

Is commonly used to **propagate** something. for instance:

> Or is the virus being spread through trade, for example, from flock to flock by contaminated equipment, egg flats, feed trucks, et cetera?

Source Linguee: [spead accross](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/spread+across.html) [spread through](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/spread+through.html)